# Measure startup performance c# application

Tags: c#, performance

I noticed that sometimes a .net 4.0 c# application takes a long time to start, without any apparent reason. Can can I determine what's actually happening, what modules are loaded? I'm using a number of external assemblies. Can putting them into the GAC improve performances?

Is .NET 4 slower than .NET 2?

Comment: Running under the debugger, `Activator.CreateInstance` is very slow on .NET 4.

Answer (score 5):

.NET programs have two distinct start-up behaviors.  They are called cold-start and warm-start.  The cold-start is the slow one, you'll get it when no .NET program was started before.  Or when the program you start is large and was never run before.  The operating system has to find the assembly files on disk, they won't be available in the file system cache (RAM).  That takes a while, hard disks are slow and there are a lot of files to find.  A small do-nothing Winforms app has to load 51 DLLs to get started.  A do-nothing WPF app weighs in at 77 DLLs.

You get a warm start when the assembly files were loaded before, not too long ago.  The assembly file data now comes from RAM instead of the slow disk, that's zippedy-doodah.  The only startup overhead is now the jitter.

There's little you can do about cold starts, the assemblies have to come of the disk one way or another.  A fast disk makes a Big difference, SSDs are especially effective.  Using ngen.exe to pre-jit an assembly actually makes the problem worse, it creates another file that needs to be found and loaded.  Which is the reason that Microsoft recommends *not* prejitting small assemblies.  Seeing this problem with .NET 4 programs is also highly indicated, you don't have a lot of programs that bind to the version 4 CLR and framework assemblies.  Not yet anyway, this solves itself over time.

There's another way this problem automatically disappears.  The Windows SuperFetch feature will start to notice that you often load the CLR and the jitted Framework assemblies and will start to pre-load them into RAM automatically.  The same kind of trick that the Microsoft Office and Adobe Reader 'optimizers' use.  They are also programs that have a lot of DLL dependencies.  Unmanaged ones, the problem isn't specific to .NET.  These optimizers are crude, they preload the DLLs when you login.  Which is the 'I'm really important, screw everything else' approach to working around the problem, make sure you disable them so they don't crowd out the RAM space that SuperFetch could use.

Comment: How do I track what's happening? I noticed that the constructor of the main form takes a lot time to execute (the InitializeComponents in particular) but this doesn't happen every time the application is started and often it takes much more time at startup.

Answer (score 1):

The startup time is most likely due to the runtime JIT compiling assembly IL into machine code for execution.  It can also be affected by the debugger - as another answerer has suggested.

Excluding that - I'll talk about an application ran 'in the wild' on a user's machine, with no debugger etc.

The JIT compiler in .Net 4 is, I think it's fair to say, better than in .Net 2 - so no; it's not slower.

You can improve this startup time significantly by running [ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on your application's assemblies - this pre-compiles the EXEs and DLLs into native images.  However you lose some flexibility by doing this and, in general, there is not much point.

You should see the startup time of some MFC apps written in C++ - all native code, and yet depending on how they are linked they can take just as long.

It does, of course, also depend on what an application is actually doing at startup!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think putting your assemblies in GAC will boot the performance.
If possible do logging for each instruction you have written on Loading or Intialize events which may help you to identify which statement is actually taking time and with this you can identify the library which is taking time in loading.

Comment: I read that having the assemblies (I have quite a number of dependences for the UI assemblies I use from Devexpress) installed in the GAC will reduce the startup time as the signature of all the assemblies needs to be verified. Is that correct?

Comment: @Andera you are right to a certain extent but it wont give you considerable boost in performance which you are looking for.. i think it will increase the performance by 15-20%. Are you using enterprise lib in your project?